# Junk email with attachment in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to send email with zip file attachment using zend framework. but always i send it go to junk directory of my email.

Here is attached code i used.

I don't know what is the problem please help me to find this. Thanks a lot.

```
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
    $mail->setBodyHtml($email_body);
    $mail->setFrom('admin@website.com', 'Stephen Nolan');
    $mail->addTo($_POST['email'], 'Kamalifestyle Client');
    $mail->setSubject('Thanks From Kamalifestyle, See Attachment');

    $attachment = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($currentFile));
    $attachment->type = 'zip';        
    $attachment->filename = "completebook.zip";

    if ($mail->send()) {
        unlink($currentFile);
        echo 'Message Sent';
        ?>

    <?php
    } else {
        echo 'Error Sending ';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$attachment->type` should be the MIME type of the attachment, not the file name extension.

Other reasons might exists why the e-mail ends up in your junk directory. Consult the manual of the software that puts the mail into the junk directory (i.e. either the mail server or the your mail user agent). For example if you IMAP server uses sieve to move messages into the junk directory based on headers added by Spam Assassin, you might want to read [Spam Assassin Wiki: False Positives](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/FalsePositives).